# Como tornar obrigatório um campo HTML?

Tags: html

Preciso validar o formulário comentários, ou seja, somente salvar se houver inserção de texto, hoje no formulário não é obrigatório a inserção de texto. Já tentei usar o [JQuery validation plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/), porém não obtive excito de como usá-lo. Quero deixar o form obrigatório seguindo o exemplo da imagem abaixo ou com qualquer tipo de inserção de texto obrigatório.

```html
<textarea cols='45' rows='7' name='comment' >
```

[image: *Formulário comentários*]

Comment: Colega, use a tag required, não precisa inventar muito. Pesquise sobre HTML5.

Comment: Ja resolvid aqui amigão.

Comment: voce poderia mostrar a alteração que fez

Answer (score 6):

O formulário é um formulário HTML, que está sendo gerado usando PHP.

Uma solução que encontrei para este campo foi adicionar o atributo  [necessário](http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-required.php) acrescentando o `required` deixando assim o campo com inserção de texto obrigatório.

```php
echo "<textarea cols='45' rows='7' name='comment' required>".$this->fields["comment"]."</textarea>";
```

Feito isto o  navegador irá informar usuário para preencher este campo.

[image: Campo de texto com balão indicativo de preenchimento obrigatório]

Answer (score 3):

Só vc adicionar o atributo `required` que seu input será obrigatório.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Buscar..." required>
```

Answer (score -1):

Como os colegas anteriores mencionaram, utilize a tag required nos inputs e por segurança inplemente um if para validação como por exemplo:

```
if(isset($_POST['emailAdmLogin']) && !empty($_POST['emailAdmLogin']) && isset($_POST['senhaAdmLogin'])&& empty($_POST['senhaAdmLogin'])){

    $emailAdmLogin = addslashes($_POST['emailAdmLogin']);
    $senhaAdmLogin = addslashes($_POST['senhaAdmLogin']);
    $this->validaAcesso($emailAdmLogin,$senhaAdmLogin);       
}else{
    header('app/Public/Admin');
}
```